# What is the difference between $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ in terms of their metrics?

Tags: metric-spaces

what is the difference between $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ in terms of their metics?

Do I need more assumptions to make difference between them beside just their metric functions?

Comment: What is the usual Euclidean metric on an (arbitrary?) countably infinite set $X$?

Comment: Do you mean a countably infinite subset of the real line?

Comment: I editted and developed the question.

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is a dense subset of $\Bbb R$, but $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$ are discrete.

Comment: What's a countably infinite vector space? $\mathbb Q^n$ perhaps?

Comment: I simplified and clarified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at $\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb N$ as metric spaces disregarding the ambient real axis, you can distinguish them.
The space $\mathbb Q$ is the only one of them without isolated points (the others have only isolated points).
The space $\mathbb N$ contains such an element that no two other elements have the same distance to it; this is false for the other two spaces.

Comment: What do you mean that "this is false for the other two spaces"?

Comment: In $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z$ there is no element with the property that no two distinct elements have the same distance to it.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean by "no two distince elements have the same distance to it." could you explain that?

Comment: In $\mathbb{N}$ you can only be "on the right" of $0$. That's what he's talking about.

Comment: @Yk26, there is no point $x\in\mathbb Z$ with this property: there are no two points $a,b$ (distinct from $x$ and each other) so that $|x-a|=|x-b|$.

Comment: I'm still confused. For example, I'm thinking $x=0$ and $a=-1$ and $b=1$ in the above explanation.

Comment: @Yk26, if you are in $\mathbb Z$, then for any $x$ the points $a=x-1$ and $b=x+1$ have the same distance to $x$. But if you are in $\mathbb N$ and $x=0$, you can't find any such $a$ and $b$.